# Why can't we represent finite field extensions as $F_{p^n}=\{0,1,2,3,...,p^n-1\}$ and work mod $p^n$

Tags: finite-fields

I know field extensions of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime are represented as a quotient group over irreducible polynomials.

For example $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}\cong\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)=\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha+1\}$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$. Is there a way to label the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ as $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and work modulo some number? I haven't been able to make a connection.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is not a field.  Of course, you can name the elements of $\mathbb F_{2^2}$ anything you like, including $\{0,1,2,3\}$ but the field operations will not be straightforward.  Note, of course, that using, e.g. $2$ as a symbol would be extremely confusing.  You are much better off with $\{0,1,\alpha, \alpha^2\}$.

Comment: Multiplication modulo $4$ is noninvertible. E.g. $2\times2=0$ where $2\neq0$. 

Working $\mod p$ gives us a field *iff.* $p$ is prime. Otherwise, $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is merely a ring.

Comment: As @lulu says, the given additive and multiplicative structure on $\{0,1,\cdots,p^n-1\}$ have *nothing* to do with the additive and multiplicative structure on $\Bbb F_{p^n}$. You might as well call the elements of $\Bbb F_4$ “red, blue, green, yellow” as “zero, one, two, three”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb F_p=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ but, for example and for using the smallest extension, $\mathbb F_{p^2}\ne\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$. In particular $p$ as element of
$\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ is non-invertible but $p$ as non-zero element of the field $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ should be invertible. This would be enough to make the difference.

However an stronger argument is that the complement of $\mathbb F_p$ in its extension $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ are not simple classes modulo $p^2$ of integers but very
strange (we could say of unimaginable nature) mathematical objects. If the number $\sqrt{-1}$ was "imaginary" for ancient people, an object in an algebraic extension of $\mathbb F_p$ would be "superimaginary" for us.

Answer (score 1):

In the field $\mathbb{F}_4$, $1 + 1 = 0$. That field has characteristic $2$. In the integers modulo $4$ you have
$1 + 1 = 2 \ne 0$.